# Is there any way to make Pandas to_sql function verbose?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to make `pandas.to_sql` function verbose, i.e to report  something like 'processing row 100 from 1000000' etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Since to_sql uses sqlalchemy as connection (con),
you should be able to get a more verbose output by activating 
the sqlalchemy logger (and potentially print that to stdout).

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#configuring-logging

Did not test it though, let me know if that could work for you and I can try to make a minimal code example.